# How to represent the complete big number (all e)

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, tokens

When I convert a variable using the functions toNumber() or toString() I obtain this result: x.toNumber()

```
1e+27
```

But I want to see the entire number with all the figures. Because If I don´t convert the number, the big number format it´s something like this:

```
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 26, c: [ 9999999500000 ] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I'm assuming you're fetching a response from a contract.

```
var theNumber;
myContract.getNumber()
.then(function(response) {
  theNumber = response;
  console.log(theNumber.toString(10));
});
```

You can lower the magnitude with `fromWei(theNumber, 'unit')`. Something like

```
var shift18;
...
  shift18 = fromWei(theNumber, 'ether'); // (18 decimals)
  console.log(shift18.toString(10));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

var value = new BigNumber(resultis.args._amount);

//converting the bignumber from wei to ether, 18 decimal, replace trailing zero

var value = (web3.fromWei(value, "ether").toFixed(18)).replace(/^0+(\d)|(\d)0+$/gm, '$1$2');